# Crystal Report Text not wrapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Using Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal Reports 13
Well, that's what it says in the web.config: Version=13.0.2000.0

When debugging with VS, the report looks fine. The text wraps just fine.
This text is in a text object and it's static text.

For instance, in one of the text objects it has two lines that read:

```
Temp Zone 1
(end)
```

When debugging, that is what it looks like and how it should look.
But upload to the 2008 R2 Server and it no longer wraps.
It looks like this on the server:

```
Temp Zone 1 (end)
```

There are about 30 reports and they are all doing this.
The changes I made when inheriting these applications is not having a separate aspx page for each report, I combined them into one aspx page that has the report name passed to it.

This is happening on the staging server. I have not made any changes on production yet but the reports on production are just fine.

When printing or saving to pdf, the text wraps just fine, it's just when on the server and viewing the report.

I have compared server settings and web.config files and everything is the same.

Is there any suggestions on what I may be overlooking when trying to fix this problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are the runtimes the same in each environment?

Comment: If you use templates for Crystal Reports, there are **sections** options where you can adjust several parameters and text wrapping is rather also present.

Comment: Does the font that you are using in the deign environment present in the production environment?

Comment: Are the production reports formatted differently at all?

Comment: It uses a typical Arial Font. The servers have the same environment. I am able to remote into both of them and compare side by side. The reports have sections and when a new report is needed, one similar is copies and then the tables are changes as well as some of the data.

Comment: The production reports are the same except for the two new ones I added. They have not been changed but the look fine on production, but not on staging. And they look ok in the Main Report Preview and when I run/debug with Visual Studio.